# Getting only one <modulename>.nocache.js file in Multiple Entry Point Module

Tags: javascript, gwt

My Project Structure has two Entry Point methods on client side in

```
ExtryGate.java
ExitGate.java
```

I have also added EntryGate.gwt.xml and ExitGate. I have carefully changed the following lines in both the files

```
<module rename-to='entrygate'>
<module rename-to='exitgate'>
```

In EntryGate.html and ExitGate.html, I have added the following lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="intellipark/entrygate.nocache.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="intellipark/exitgate.nocache.js"></script>
```

The problem is that I have only one nocache.js file i.e. only entrygate.nocache.js file. How can I generate exitgate.nocahce.js file? Is there any dependency on .gwt.rpc file as well? Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `exitgate.nocache.js` to be generated, you have to pass the `ExitGate` module name to the GWT Compiler. You can either run the Compiler twice (once for each module), or run it once passing the two modules as arguments.

The `*.gwt.rpc` files will be distinct for each module (but the same servlet *might* be able to serve both module's RPC, in case you use the same `RemoteService` interface in both modules)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I successfully got the exitgate.nocahce.js. Qucik Question: I am unable to see it's effect on the HTML page. I created the 'HTML page' and 'exitgate.gwt.xml' manually. Are they supposed to be generated during the compile process? What supposedly, am I doing wrong in getting the output in HTML file? I have already added the following line in HTML?

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="intellipark/exitgate.nocache.js"></script>